# Combine xml's and getting the ouput as a proper xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a requirement to combine 4 xml files into one. They are like follows. 
**Document 1**

```
<doc1>
....
<doc1>
```

**Document 2**

```
<doc2>
....
<doc2>
```

**Document 3**

```
<doc3>
....
<doc3>
```

**Document 4**

```
<doc4>
....
<doc4>
```

I want the output as follows

```
<doc1>
....

<doc2>
....
</doc2>


<doc3>
....
</doc3>


<doc4>
....
</doc4>
</doc1>
```

I did it as follows.

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc1.xml')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc2.xml')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc3.xml')"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc4.xml')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

but the ouput I get is as follows

```
<doc1>
....
</doc1>


<doc2>
....
</doc2>


<doc3>
....
</doc3>


<doc4>
....
</doc4>
```

Is it possible to change my script and get what I want?

Comment: harsh, Was my answer useful to you or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This transformation produces the wanted result:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:for-each select="document('doc1.xml')/*">
            <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()"/>

             <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc2.xml')"/>
             <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc3.xml')"/>
             <xsl:copy-of select="document('doc4.xml')"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, this works, but I have a small problem. When I bring them into one file manually it has more information than when I use use your way. Can you please tell me why this happens?

Comment: @harsh: What do you mean by "it has more information"? Can you provide concrete information, please? Ideally, you would edit the question, would provide the exact XML documents (as few and as small as possible) and also the exact wanted result. At present this information is not provided, therefore it isn't surprizing that a suggested solution produces results that are different from what you *imagined* the results must be.

Comment: the files are very big. thats why i didnt post them. Some namespace duplicates are avoided in the code. so even better. just now noticed that, thanks. :)